# Is it posible to view react native source code in built applications?

Tags: xamarin, react-native

I am a developer who wants to be able to make cross-platform applications and have came across Xamarin and React Native.

Since the language that Xamarin uses is C#, this means that the code has to be compiled before the application can be run. React Native, however, uses JavaScript. Since JavaScript source code can be seen on websites, and is downloaded into the webpage unlike PHP, this means that the user on the client end can easily view the source code. If the user is able to get to the source code easily and the application in question connects to a database, this means they would be able to view the password, making the application insecure.

The question is, if I where to make an application which connects to a MySQL using React Native, would the user be able to easily view the source code like they can on a webpage, or is it compiled like Xamarin is, making it harder to view the source code?

Comment: If your security concept is that the user should not be able to read the source code, I would recommend you to rethink your security concept. Kerckhoffs' principle: A cryptosystem should be secure even if everything about the system, except the key, is public knowledge. Security through obscurity is also discouraged by NIST.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The javascript does not compile to native code. It uses a bridge to communicate between javascript/native components. JS is obfuscated but that is about it. You should not be storing any secrets client side.

See: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1093
'As @vjeux said, we have no immediate plans to add encryption for JS bundle files, and yes, under the currently recommended bundling instructions, your JS will be included as plaintext that can be extracted and de-obfuscated with relative ease.'

He goes on to mention a way to base64 encode the jsbundle to deter 'casual' hackers but then explains it will not stop a 'determined hacker'.

You should not connect the client directly to the DB. You need a secure server to handle authentication, and retrieve and validate db queries.

Nothing is secure on client. So you must validate all db queries before calling the db with them. See: https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/ 'An SQL Injection needs just two conditions to exist – a relational database that uses SQL, and *a user controllable input which is directly used in an SQL query.*'

By allowing the client to directly connect to the DB, you cannot prevent the oldest of attacks.

Comment: So if I wanted to connect to a database, or store any sensitive data such as API secrets, then Xamarin would be a better choice?

Comment: Don't store API secrets on client. Keep them on server. Server is the only secure part of the whole operation and to think you can compile c# and it be 'secure' is naive. The server should connect to the DB and relay any necessary information to the client. You can store API tokens on client, but keep the secret on server and do validation/anything secure there.

Comment: I ment API token. So I would not want to store database information on a React Native application then?

Comment: Like the database location/username/pw? No. Where would you validate/clean the database queries to ensure the client doesn't try anything malicious?

Comment: That's what I was meaning. So in this case, Xamarin would need to be used.

Comment: Nope, everything that is **not** on the server is potentially unsafe. Xamarin clients can be decompiled as well, with a little effort (Android is easier to decompile than iOS in my experience). Never store secrets in your clients.

Comment: You should also never directly connect to a database like MySQL in your client. That is the reason why (REST) API's are used, which you can secure with OAuth for example.

Comment: @iProgram you don't wanna store secrets directly in your code, regardless of where it runs. For storage of sensitive data on React Native you may use https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain (I am a co-author)